# Harmonic function (PDE) - Orthogonal matrix

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

> > Let $u\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be harmonic in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. 
> >     $$
> > \Delta u:=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_k^2}=0\mbox{ in }\mathbb{R}^n.
> > $$
> >     Let $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ be an orthogonal matrix (i.e. $QQ^T=E_n$). Show that then the function $v\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $v(y):=u(x)$ with $y=Qx$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{R}^n$, too.

Hello, it is to show that $\Delta v=0$. So I already started with
$$
y=\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\\vdots\\y_n\end{pmatrix}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}q_{11}\ldots q_{1n}\\\vdots\\q_{n1}\ldots q_{nn}\end{pmatrix}}_{=Q}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\\vdots\\x_n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}q_{1i}x_i\\\vdots\\\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}q_{ni}x_i\end{pmatrix},
$$
getting then
$$
\Delta v(y)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\partial^2 v(y)}{\partial\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}q_{ki}x_i\right)^2}.
$$
Now I would like to know how I can continue at this point.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You should continue by $\frac {\partial v}{\partial x_k}=\sum_i \frac {\partial v}{\partial y_i}.\frac {\partial y_i}{\partial x_k}$ and then find $\frac {\partial^2 v}{\partial y_i^2}$

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you are doing. Could you please explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $y_l=\sum_{i=1}q_{li}x_i$ then
$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}=\sum_{l=1}^{n}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y_l}.q_{li}$

and

$\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x_i\partial x_k}=\sum_{l=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial y_l\partial y_j}.q_{li}.q_{ji}$

then

$\Delta v=\sum_{l=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial y_l\partial y_j} (\sum_{i=1}^{n}q_{li}.q_{ji})=\Delta u$

Comment: Hm, why are you considering the derivations of y concerning the $x_i$?... Dont see why one can $\Delta v$ in a double sum... Is that a chain rule or something like that?

Comment: I solved question  by $v(x)=u(y)$ that $Qx=y$,and I really do not undrestand what do you mean. in each step I use chain rule and $\Delta u$ is achived by $l=j$

Comment: I am new in this and still do not see how you got your results but maybe I see later.

Comment: Maybe you can explain it step by step: I still have $\Delta v(y)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\partial^2 v(y)}{\partial (\sum_{i=1}^{n}q_{ki}x_i)^2}$ and do not know the next step, sorry.

Comment: I got it! The chain rule was my fault.

Comment: But: How will you divergate u to $y_j$?... is that right there is the partial divergation from u to an $y_j$?...

Comment: Please think about that, you should solve $v(x)=u(y)$ and  no $v(y)=u(x)$. it does not  have  any problem.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the second line there should be a k